# Macro to "Save as" workbook 2 from the data in a cell from Workbook 1

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a basic user to macros but am now stuck with the following dilemma.
I have two workbooks open. I need to "Save As" and close workbook 2 with a file name from a cell in Workbook 1. The macro is running from workbook 1.
Sorry but this is as far as I could get from the internet. I'm guessing a change in the last line. Oh yeah, I don't know what Dim means either.

```
Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String

FPath = "G:"

FName = Sheets("sheet 1").Range("A1").Text

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
```

Answer (score 3):

Dim is how you Dimension (declare your variable), in your case, telling the code that `FName` will refer to a string value that you assign. For a nice tutorial see [This link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx)

To get your code to work, try this:

```
Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String

FPath = "G:"

FName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("A1").Text 'use ThisWorkbook since you are running from Workbook1

With Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx")
    .SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName 
    .Close True '-> use false to not save changes
End With
'here you need to tell VBA what specific workbook you want to save
'if you used ThisWorkbook here, you would save the workbook where the code runs from, which is Workbook1
```

You could also take a better approach like so:

```
Dim FName as String, FPath as String
Dim wkb1 as Workbook, wkb2 as Workbook

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook '-> or Set wkb1 = Workbooks("workbook1")

FPath = "G:"
FName = wkb1.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("A1").Text

Set wkb2 = Workbooks("workbook2")
With wkb2
    .SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
    .Close True '-> use false to not save changes
End With
```

Comment: Beautiful. Works like a charm.

Comment: Great @user1706708. If you feel like this solved your problem, then please check it as the answer so others can benefit in the future.

Comment: Sorry guys but I also need to close Workbook 2 as well if i can

Comment: @user1706708. I've edited the both pieces of code above. Closing the workbook is very easy :)

Answer (score 2):

As the others have state, Dim stands for dimension.

Historically speaking, in various BASIC (Beginner's All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code) programming languages, you didn't have to declare variables -- with the exception of arrays, which had to be declared.  So, even very old BASIC languages had a way to declare arrays, this done using the "Dim" keyword.  When basic languages grew up a bit an begun to support declaring regular variables, they simply borrowed the already in use keyword Dim.  So Dim stands for dimension, originally used to indicate the size and/or bounds of an array, but taken over to declare variables of any kind.

As an aside, as a programming language evolves, its language designers are typically reticent to introduce new keywords because doing so will often break existing programs.  For example, had they introduced a "var" keyword, it likely would have broken many existing programs that use "var" as a variable name.  It is not uncommon to find an existing keyword more-or-less repurposed for added functionality as a language evolves.

Comment: Sorry guys but I also need to close Workbook 2 as well if i can

Comment: Understood, no problem.  I think this is why it's best etiquette to ask two separate questions in separate posts (even if they're related), so you can accept both answers independently.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.
You COULD just change the last lien to this and it would work:

```
Workbooks("Workbook2Filename.xls").SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
```

However, i'd recomend the following approach:

```
Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String

Dim wbBook1 As Workbook
Dim wbBook2 As Workbook

Set wbBook1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbBook2 = Workbooks("Workbook2Filename.xls") 'assumed workbook 2 is already open

FPath = "G:"
FName = wbBook1.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("A1").Text

wbBook2.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName

Set wbBook1 = Nothing
Set wbBook2 = Nothing
```

Dim stands for Dimension, and it's how you tell VBA to make a variable to store information into.